# Form won't submit in jquery after radio button change

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a form with radio buttons in them.  I loop through the radio button groups to determine if they are all checked.  If not, I am not submitting the form, otherwise submit the form.

The issue is when it fails the first time, going back and selecting all radios, resubmitting doesnt submit the form.  Although I added alerts in there, it is hitting the submit part but not actually submitting.

```
$('#submit-fee').click(function(){
    var bValid = false;
    $('input[type="radio"]').each(function(index) {
        if($('input[name="'+$(this).attr('name')+'"]:checked').val() == "YES" || $('input[name="'+$(this).attr('name')+'"]:checked').val() == "NO"){
            bValid = true;
        }else{
            bValid = false;
            return false;
        }
    });
    if(!bValid){
        alert("Please make sure all questions are answered.");
        $('#rec-fee-form').submit(function () { 
            return false; 
        }); 
    }else{
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this --

```
$('#rec-fee-form').submit(function(){
    var bValid = false;
    $('input[type="radio"]').each(function(index) {
        if($('input[name="'+$(this).attr('name')+'"]:checked').val() == "YES" || $('input[name="'+$(this).attr('name')+'"]:checked').val() == "NO"){
            bValid = true;
        }else{
            bValid = false;
        }
    });
    if(!bValid){
        alert("Please make sure all questions are answered.");
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Not quite.  That was what i was doing before.  The form still submits with this example.  Also, the alert never gets hit.  It's weird

Comment: Ok, that did actually work.  So this example still needs the return false in there after the bValid variable is set to false in the loop.

Comment: @user1515224 when you return from within `each` you are actually returning from `.each()` and not from your submit handler